# Make search menu and navigation menu onOptionsItemSelected work together?

Tags: android

I have this onOptionsItemSelected for a search menu button in mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
```

...

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_search:
                search();
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and this in baseactivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
```

...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    //int id = item.getItemId();
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    nDrawerLayout.closeDrawers(); //close menu after click
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

but with the two I can't make none of them work. (click not working both)

any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` in your main activity, if you did not consume click. Then onOptionItemSelected will be called in BaseActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            search();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionItemSelected(item);
}
```